# Finite solvable groups with abelian Fitting subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be any finite solvable group with Fitting subgroup
$F(G)$. Which conditions on $F(G)$ makes $G$ to be supersolvable?
(It is well-known that any finite solvable group with cyclic Fitting subgroup
is supersolvable). In particular, if $F(G)$ is abelian which conditions on
$F(G)$ (and $G$) are needed for $G$ being supersolvable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relation between supersolvability of a finite group and its Fitting
subgroup is that for a finite group $G$ the following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is supersolvable.
2. $G' \leq {\rm Fit}(G)$ and ${\rm Fit}(G)$ is the product of cyclic
    and weak $S$-quasinormal subgroups of $G$ of prime power orders.

Here a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called *weak* $S$- *quasinormal* in $G$
if, for every $p \in \pi(G)$, there is at least one Sylow $p$-subgroup
of $G$ that permutes with $H$. -- See Theorem 2 in

Piroska Csörgö, [*On Supersolvability of Finite Groups*](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ43_03%2FS0017089501030129a.pdf&code=584e444c4bf13c327ed3eff3d6c22b2f),
  Glasgow Math. J. 43(2001), 327-333.

Comment: Dear Stefan, many thanks for the answer and reference.

Answer (score 3):

Just a remark really. If $G$ is any finite solvable group, it is well-known that 
$F(G/\Phi(G)) = F(G)/\Phi(G)$. Since $\Phi(F(G)) \leq \Phi(G)$, we see that $H = G/\Phi(G)$ has $F(H)$ Abelian of squarefree exponent. Hence the requirement that $F(G)$ be Abelian in the question of itself puts almost no restriction on the structure of $G$.

Comment: Dear Geoff, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Stefan Kohl gave a much more comprehensive answer than I did, so I do not think you should have changed the acceptance of his answer.

Comment: Yes, but you focused on my question.However, I changed the acceptance of answer again. Many thanks again.

Comment: Obviously, $G$ is supersolvable  iff all indices of a chief series of $G$ containing  $F(G)$ and lying below $F(G)$ are primes (i.e., $F(G)$ is supersolvable immersed in $G$, in terminology of R. Baer),